# Remove Repeated Words from Text file

Tags: vb.net, file, text, words

I have a text file, contaning nearly 45,000 words, one word in each line. Thousands of these words appear more than 10 times. I want to create a new file in which there is no repeated word. I used Stream reader but it reads the file only once. How can I get rid of the repeated words. Please help me. Thanks
 My code was like this

```
Try
        File.OpenText(TextBox1.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Dim line As String = String.Empty
    Dim OldLine As String = String.Empty
    Dim sr = File.OpenText(TextBox1.Text)

    line = sr.ReadLine
    OldLine = line

    Do While sr.Peek <> -1
        Application.DoEvents()
        line = sr.ReadLine
        If OldLine <> line Then
                My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Splitted File without Repeats.txt", line & vbCrLf, True)
        End If

        OldLine = line
    Loop


    sr.Close()
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop & "\Splitted File without Repeats.txt")
    MsgBox("Loop terminated. Stream Reader Closed." & vbCrLf)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `Distinct()` method for this.

This will work for smaller files:

```
Dim lines As String() = File.ReadAllLines("yourfile.txt")
File.WriteAllLines("yourfile.txt", lines.Distinct().ToArray())
```

Comment: Sure dear Rakitić . You desreve it.